# In a DC motor, why would the rotor oscillate around its stable equilibrium point, had there been a constant current?

Tags: torque, electromagnetic-induction, equilibrium

If I choose to replace the commutator in the motor with two slip rigs like those in the AC dynamo, then when the plane of the motor is normal to the magnetic field, aligning, therefore, the magnetic dipole $\vec{μ}$ with the magnetic field $\vec{B}$. My question is Why in this position the rotor would oscillate up and down around that stable equilibrium point given that $\vec{τ}=0$?